# Почему не выводится список новых тем из базы данных на странице списка тем?

Tags: python, django

Не могу вывести список новых тем из базы данных на странице списка тем. Хотя другом шаблоне могу вывести.

```
    `views.py
def modal_topic(request):
    topic = Topic.objects.order_by('-id')[0:5]
    return render(request,  'modal_new_topics.html', {'topic': topic})

class TopicListView(ListView):
      model = Topic
      queryset = Topic.objects.all()

      template_name = 'index.html'

    index.html
   {% for item in topic %}
      {{ item.name }}

  {% if not forloop.last %}: {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете ListView то по умолчанию в шаблоне queryset доступен по
переменной object_list

```
  class TopicListView(ListView):
     model = Topic
     template_name = 'index.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Topic.objects.order_by('-id')[:5]

  {% for object in object_list %}

     <p>{{ object.name }}</p>

   <hr/>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, конечно за ответ, но мне нужно вывести именно последние темы в колличестве 5 штук, а не все. По вашему совету я все темы получаю.
topic = Topic.objects.order_by('-id')[0:5]
именно эти топики нужно получить.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Обновил ответ))